# getstream.io: Adding activities to a user's feed without a following relation

Tags: getstream-io

I'm currently developing a networking application where I'm using activity streams. At first getstream looked like it would save my day but I soon stumbled upon a hurdle: in my system a user can follow other users, organisations and groups (polymorphic Actor class), so far so good. But a user's feed should also include activities by actors the user does not follow but which are tagged with a topic/tag the user have stated an interest in (basically the user "follows" one or more tags). Then I found the "To" field in the documentation which looked like it could solve my problem, until I read a few more lines and saw that it was limited to 100 targets. Is this this limit etched in stone? Or is there maybe another feature I haven't seen which can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activities added to a feed via the `to` field, are also sent to its followers, this allows you to create more complex flows like the one you describe.

For example: say that the feed `news:tommaso` follows the feed `tag:programming`. When you add an activity to a feed `news:hackernews` and add `tag:programming` in the list of "to" targets, `news:tommaso` will receive the activity in its feed as well.

Comment: But what about the 100-limit on the "To field"? If 1000 users follows tag:programming will 900 be "left out of the loop"?

Comment: Do I just repeat the request (post the activity) as many times as I need to reach all recipients?

Comment: @HankDenijm the limitation is only on the size of the `to` target list, not on the amount of feeds that will get the activity. in your example all 1000 feeds would get the update

Comment: Ahhh, my hemmorhage. Thanks Tommaso.